# Projectile Motion Components of Velocity and Speed

Tags: kinematics, projectile

In kinematics, I am told that the vertical velocity at the apex of projectile motion is 0. There is still a constant horizontal velocity. Given this, are we not allowed to generalize and say that at the apex, the velocity is 0?

In addition, the speed will never be 0 at the apex because the horizontal velocity is non-zero, right?

Comment: The speed can be 0 if the horizontal velocity is 0. That is, if the projectile is moving straight up, the vertical and horizontal velocity will be 0 at the apex.

Answer (score 0):

I will use Cartesian coordinates. Assuming you are talking about 2D projectiles, your velocity will be given as:

$\textbf{v}(t) = \dot{x}_{initial} \hat{x} + (\dot{y}_{initial} - gt)\hat{y} $

What happens at the apex is that $t=\frac{\dot{y}_{initial}}{g}$, so that the **y-component** of the velocity vanishes as that instant. Evidently, the x-component of the velocity does not depend on time, and hence can only be zero if it is initially zero. Thus, the velocity will be zero at the apex iff the x-component of the velocity is initially zero.

Answer (score 0):

Speed is the magnitude, $|\bar{v}|=\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2 +v_z^2}$, of the velocity vector, $\bar{v}=(v_x,v_y,v_z)$. So, yes, the speed of the projectile is nonzero at the apex (unless it's thrown straight up in the air, of course).

Answer (score 0):

The net velocity at the apex will simply be the vector sum of the horizontal and vertical components of the velocity.
The **vertical component of velocity** varies with time as - ***V(t) = U(y) - gt***
And obviously at the apex it becomes zero after **t = U(y)/g**
On the other hand the horizontal component of velocity remains "v cos θ" for the time of flight.
For it to be zero you need only 2 requirements :-
Either v = 0; which means you have'nt thrown the particle or;
cos θ becomes zero which implies that θ is $π/2.$